# Firewall to Load Balancer throughput

Tags: networking, load-balancing

I have a theory question for you networking guru's if wouldn't mind answering :). Let's say I have a Cisco ASA 5510 who's cleartext throughput is **300Mbps** and sitting behind that I have Citrix MPX 5650 who's throughput is **1Gbps** - everything is connected to a 1Gbps Access swich. Will my load-balancer ever get to push 1Gbps of throughput if my FW only supports 300Mbps, but I'm on 1Gb access switches? The ASA has a 1Gb Interface, so I'm curious why have 1Gb interface if you can only process 300Mbps of throughput?

```
Firewall > Load Balancer > Web Servers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't really run `300Mbps` throughput over a `100Mbps` connection :P
Also, you are limited to the weakest link (least throughput) when establishing a connection.

Say you have the following (this is for teaching not really real life):

```
      Host1   Host2
          /    \
      10mbps   100mbps
          \    /
            R1
            |
          1000mbps
            |
          Host3
```

List showing communications and max throughput

- Host3 and Host1 = 10mbps
- Host3 and Host2 = 100mbps
- Host3 and R1 = 1000mbps
- Host2 and Host1 = 10mbps
- R1 and Host1 = 10mbps
- R1 and Host2 = 100mpbs

So to answer your question, if the the application/server that is being accessed by the hosts has to go through the ASA, then yes the max throughput you'll get is 300mpbs.

Comment: +1 for Nice diagram :). I'm not concerned with the host/server speed since it's all 1Gb. I'm more curious about the ASA to load-balancer

Comment: If the throughput is only 300mbps max and your links are Gigabit, then your throughput will only be 300mpbs max.